# Kinds of closedness for convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $S\subseteq X$ be a convex subset. I guess that the following are all equivalent:

(i) $S$ is weakly sequentially closed.

(ii) $S$ is sequentially closed.

(iii) $S$ is closed.

(iv) $S$ is weakly closed.

My attempt:

(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) This follows from the fact that every strongly convergent sequence is also weakly convergent with the same limit.

(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii) Automatic, holds for any metric space.

(iii) $\Rightarrow$ (iv) This follows because for a convex set, the concepts of closed and weakly closed coincides.

(iv) $\Rightarrow$ (i) Automatic, holds for any topological space.

Is this right? Do we need more hypothesis on $X$? Like be a reflexive space or something.

Comment: Looks fine. No further assumptions needed.

Comment: For the last part, I think you should say "for any topological **vector** space" .